# How to get a line density from list density plot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a list density plot from a list `ls={{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2}}...`. **How can I extract the line density with a fix `y`, such that I could get a `ListPlot` `{{xi,zi},{xj,zj}}...`.** Please start from list `ls` or the graph `p1`, avoid using the functions, they are only used to generate the list.

The graph in ListDensityPlot is smooth, so I would require the ListPlot also be smooth. However, the list `ls` may not be very dense. Below is the code creating the list and ListDensityPlot:

```
(*Creating a list ls*)
f[x_] := Sqrt[1 - x];
stepSize = 100/1000;
ls0 = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 1, stepSize}];
ls1 = Flatten[
   Table[{#[[1]], y, Exp[y - #[[2]]] - 1}, {y, #[[2]], 1.5, 
       stepSize}] & /@ ls0, 1];
ls2 = Flatten[
   Table[{#[[1]], y, 0}, {y, 0, #[[2]], stepSize}] & /@ ls0, 1];
ls = Join[ls1, ls2];
(*Draw the ListDensity of ls*)

p1 = ListDensityPlot[ls, PlotLegends -> Automatic];
p2 = Plot[{0.83, 1.14}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Red}, {Dashed, Green}}];
Show[p1, p2]
ListPointPlot3D[ls]
```

[image]

**For example, how to extract the red and green dashed line smoothly?**

[image]

It can be seen that the points may not be dense.

Comment: `f[x]` is undefined.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Sorry, added

Comment: @buzhidao - In your previous question you specified that you did not want an interpolation function to be used, but in this case I don't see how to avoid it since 0.83 and 1.14 are not points that are explicitly included in the y values of `ls`

Comment: @JasonB This is a different question, use it as you wish... I choose this two value on purpose. However, it would be best if the extracted data reflect the color in the listdensityplot.

Comment: @buzhidao  So, is an interpolation function from the `List` that goes into the `DensityPlot` acceptable, or do you wish the extracted data to be from the `DensityPlot` itself?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Both should be OK, the requirement is that the extracted data fits well in the ListPointPlot, just as shown by Jason B. However, I am afraid if I get the stepSize smaller the interpolation function will be very slow, will it?

Comment: @buzhidao  At some point, smaller step size will increase running time a lot.  Try it to see whether it matters in your case.

Comment: @buzhidao  By the way, it is possible to extract the desired information directly from the `DensityPlot`, but a lot of work would be involved.

Comment: @bbgodfrey how can one extract that? The best way of course is to extract information directly from the graph itself, since i think interpolation to list won't be identical to the interpolation made by ListDensityPlot itself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative, which is my go-to method of extracting these kinds of things. First construct a 3D-plot of the data using `Mesh` lines that sit at y-values of 0.83 and 1.14:

```
p3 = ListPlot3D[ls
  , PlotRange -> All
  , InterpolationOrder -> 1
  , MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), Mesh -> {{0.83, 1.14}}
  , BoundaryStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Then extract the lines from the graph:

```
lns = Cases[Normal@p3, Line[a_] :> a, Infinity];
ListLinePlot /@ Apply[{#1, #3} &, lns, {2}]
```

[image]

To see the points, consider:

```
Plot[Interpolation[{#1, #3} & @@@ #, InterpolationOrder -> 0][t], {t, 0, 1}] & /@ lns
```

[image]

Comment: This method is great! Two questions: How to change the two mesh lines into the color and style as shown in my plot?

Comment: `ListLinePlot[{#1, #3} & @@@ #] & /@ lns`.This code snippet is insane, it seems a pure function in another pure function. I don't quite understand it, though I know what it does.  It seems that `lns` and 
`# & /@ lns` are same but `{#1, #3} & @@@ lns` and 
`{#1, #3} & @@@ # & /@ lns` are very different... Can you explain how this code works in some detail?

Comment: @buzhidao. `lns` is a list containing the two lists of points corresponding to the two plots. Everything preceding the `/@ lns` is just a pure function which operates on each of these lists of points (thus making two `ListLinePlot`s). `{#1, #3} & @@@ #` is then really just `{#1, #3} & @@@ <list of points in 3D>`. It could also be written as `{#[[1]], #[[3]]} & /@ #` or, more straightforwardly, `Table[pt[[{1,3}]], {pt, #}]`.

Comment: Wrapping `Show[...]` around the 'ListLinePlot[{#1, #3} & @@@ #] & /@ lns' does what I'm looking for, but doesn't differentiate each line by color.  How can I do that (and add a legend)?

Comment: @user12734. `ListLinePlot[Apply[{#1, #3} &, lns, {2}], PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Answer (score 7):

So your interpolation function will suffer a bit since the data is on a non-rectangular grid.  This is the case also for the density plot, you can see that the interpolation on the 2D plot isn't great.

```
intfunc = Interpolation[DeleteDuplicates@ls]
```

[image]

You can see that the result isn't perfectly smooth,

```
Plot[{intfunc[x, .83], intfunc[x, 1.14]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

But you can also see that it matches your data points as well

```
ListPointPlot3D[{ls, {#, .83, intfunc[#, .83]} & /@ 
   Range[0, 1, .1], {#, 1.14, intfunc[#, 1.14]} & /@ Range[0, 1, .1]},
  PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[.01], Blue}, {PointSize[.01], 
    Red}, {PointSize[.01], Green}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Extracting data directly from `ListDensityPlot`

make a grayscale plot:

```
p1 = ListDensityPlot[ls, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

[image]

extract the polynomials from the graphics , then the ones that cross the desired line:

```
polys = Cases[Normal@p1, Polygon[v_List, VertexColors -> c_List], 
   Infinity];
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], 
   Select[ polys, 
    Max[#[[1, All, 2]]] > 1.14 && Min[#[[1, All, 2]]] < 1.14 & ],
  Red, Line[{{0, 1.14}, {1, 1.14}}]} ]
```

[image]

then extract the edges that cross..

```
tedges[poly_, y_] :=
 MapThread[{ {poly[[1, #1]], poly[[2, 2, #1]]}  , {poly[[1, #2]], 
     poly[[2, 2, #2]]} } & ,
  ({#, RotateLeft[#]} &@Range[Length@poly[[1]]])]
crossedges[polys_, y_] := 
  Select[  Flatten[
    tedges[#, y] & /@ (Select[ polys, 
       Max[#[[1, All, 2]]] > y && Min[#[[1, All, 2]]] < y & ]), 
    1] , ((Max[#[[All, 1, 2]] ] >= y && 
           Min[#[[All, 1, 2]] ] <= y) &)];
```

linear interpolate edge color along each edge:

```
intedge[edge_, y_] := 
 Module[{ ci = (y - edge[[2, 1, 2]])/(edge[[1, 1, 2]] - 
       edge[[2, 1, 2]])},
  {edge[[1, 1, 1]] ci + edge[[2, 1, 1]] (1 - ci)  , 
   edge[[1, 2]] ci + edge[[2, 2]] (1 - ci)}]
ListPlot[Union[intedge[#, 1.14] & /@ crossedges[polys, 1.14]]]
```

[image]

note the scale here is the grayscale..
go back and use `ColorFunctionScaling->False` for the plot..

[image]

and...after all that we see we have precisely the same result as JasonB's `Interpolation`..

[image]